# Setting up sub domain include filter in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I am trying to set up a sub domain include filter in google analytics. I am a little confused about how to write the filter pattern for my sub domain which is going to be www.somesite.com/de

All of the tutorials show it set up like this: sub1.website.com. but my url structure is different. Am I missing the point here any help appreciated.

Here is a screen of what I am trying to set up:

[image: Screen of include sub domain filter set up]

Comment: This is what I think the filter field should be just need some one to confirm for me www\.somesite\.com/de

Comment: This is incorrect.  Read the first 3 rows of "[Custom Filter Fields](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034380)" from Google. `www\.somesite\.com` is the Hostname and `^/de` is the Request URI per my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need two separate filters to accomplish this.

- **Hostname**: The full domain name of the page requested. For example: for http://www.google-analytics.com/requestURL/index.html?sample=text the hostname is www.google-analytics.com

[image: HostName Filter]

- **Request URI**: Includes the relative URL, or piece of the URL after the hostname. For example: for http://www.google-analytics.com/requestURL/index.html?sample=text the Request URI is /requestURL/index.html?sample=text

[image: Request URI Filter]

Source: [Custom Filter Fields](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034380)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Is the hostname filter applied to the main domain and the second applied to sub domain or are both applied to sub domain?

Comment: See the Google Analytics Custom Filter Fields article: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034380

Comment: I was trying to follow the Urls you added to the page and there broken so I can't see where each filter has to go

Comment: I understand how to set them up just don't get whether the first filter needs to be applied to www.somesite.com and the second applied to www.somesite/de.

Comment: A subdomain is "www.example.com" vs "subdomain.example.com".  You're asking to filter something where the "Request URI starts with `/de`". Read the top two rows of the [Google Analytics Custom Filter Fields](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034380) again and see the images above.

Comment: ahh I see where I have got confused, its the terminology that Is being used that is wrong

Answer (score -1):

The confusion here was the terminology being used. I was being asked to set up sub domain tracking when our developer was using sub directories for our different countries websites.

I have now set up filters on each of the sub directories. Here is an example of a filter to include only traffic to the sub directory /at

[image: sub directory filter]